# Is it safe to assume "java.util.ImmutableCollections" are always ordered?

Tags: java, collections, immutability

`java.util.ImmutableCollections` provides implementations for immutable `Collections`, as generated by static methods like `List.of()`, `Set.of()`, `Map.of()`; it's array-based internally. Is it safe to assume that Collections produced by said methods are always ordered?

If I have e. g. a method argument `T t` of Class type `java.util.ImmutableCollections.MapN`, can I (since it's a hidden internal Class) rely on

```
public static <T> boolean isOrderedMap(final T t) {
    final boolean isOrderedMap = "java.util.ImmutableCollections.MapN".equals(t.getClass().getCanonicalName()) 
       || t instanceof LinkedHashMap 
       || t instanceof SortedMap
       || t instanceof EnumMap
       || t instanceof Attributes
    return isOrderedMap ? true : false;
}
```

and assume that the result is indeed always true for such standard `Maps`, if they're supposed to be ordered (and similar for `Sets` and `Lists`)?

Comment: It is safe to assume a List is always ordered.  Set.of does not return a NavigableSet and Map.of does not return a NavigableMap, so **no,** you cannot safely assume they will have any particular ordering.  (And you shouldn’t even assume a non-public class like ImmutableCollections exists;  the next version of Java may or may not choose to provide immutable collections and Maps in an entirely different manner.)

Comment: Does it say "ImmutableCollections are always ordered" in the doc?  If not, it's not safe to assume they are.

Comment: It’s not even safe to assume that the class `java.util.ImmutableCollections.MapN` exists. What do you even mean with “ordered”? The order has entirely different semantics for `LinkedHashMap` and `SortedMap`. What is your actual requirement? By the way, there’s no point in the type parameter `T` here, it does not add anything to the method compared to just declare the parameter as `Object t`. Further, don’t write expressions like `condition? true: false`. Just use `condition`.

Comment: @ArfurNarf : doc doesn't state that the resulting `ImmutableCollection` is unordered. It doesn't is tell anything about the ordering, from what I see.

@Holger : by "ordered" I mean whether or not the `Iterator` from the resulting `Map` or `Set` will iterate elements in the order they were added to the Collection with e.g. `Set.of()`, or `Map.of()`. Lists should always be ordered, that's understood.

Comment: @VGR : I'd like to determine, whether a given `EntrySet` from a `Map` or a `Set` is ordered, meaning, an `Iterator` from it will return elements in the order they were added - whithout creating a `Spliterator` from it just for the sake of getting the `Spliterator.ORDERED` characteristic. There're also other types, like `EnumMap` or `Attributes` that are ordered. In particular, I'm in the unclear about the outcomes of static methods like `Set.of(E... elements)`, `Map.ofEntries(Entry... entries)`.

Comment: Then check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable).  It’s very clear about such collections:  “The iteration order of set elements is unspecified and is subject to change.”  So the answer is, **the objects returned by Set.of and Map.of will never have a consistent order.**  Honestly, when I need a consisting ordering, I just use `new ArrayList<>(existingCollection)`.  The new List contains references, not copies of the objects, so it’s not expensive.

Comment: re *It doesn't is tell anything about the ordering, from what I see.*    "The iteration order .. is unspecified and is subject to change." [Set interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html).  [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html).   But ultimately it's your code; you can decide what undocumented assumptions you are willing to rely on.

Comment: the documentation does not guarantee any order, it even specifies explicitly that there is none. even worse (for you), same `Set` created via `of` methods, will differ in the output from run to run, and this is [on purpose](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#L53..L59)

Comment: @Eugene TLDR; where in the source code does the non-ordering purpose manifest exactly?

Comment: @fozzybear everywhere where you iterate the elements.

Comment: @Eugene I meant: where in the source code of `ImmutableCollections`, which you've linked here, is the (non-ordered) 'on purpose' aspect explicitly documented?

Comment: this has already been told you by VGR: "the objects returned by Set.of and Map.of will never have a consistent order"

Comment: Oh alright, sorry - I missed the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've been looking in the wrong place of the documentation - in the method's documentations instead of the `Interface` specifications, where the immutable variants are explicitly described - and indeed the `ImmutableCollections`' static methods mentioned above generate `Sets` and  `Maps` without explicit ordering, which can be verified, e. g.:

```
  final Map<String, String> map1 = Map.of("","", " ", " ");
  final boolean isOrderedM1a = map1.keySet().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
  final boolean isOrderedM1b = map1.values().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
  final boolean isOrderedM1c = map1.entrySet().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
  final Map map2 = Map.ofEntries(new SimpleEntry("",""), new SimpleEntry(" ", " "));
  final boolean isOrderedM2a = map2.keySet().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
  final boolean isOrderedM2b = map2.values().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
  final boolean isOrderedM2c = map2.entrySet().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
  final Set set1 = Set.of(""," ");
  final boolean isOrderedS1 = set1.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
  final Set set2 = Set.of("");
  final boolean isOrderedS2 = set2.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
```

The results all are `false`, as to be expected. In contrast, immutable Collections generated from `List.of()` are always ordered, which wasn't questioned here, though. Thanks for the clarification.

Initially, I've spotted a `Spliterator` result of `true` in the code somewhere while looking for an answer, which made me believe that these static methods might produce ordered results in general. Perhaps that was due to mixing up wrapped results of `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` and similar generated test data from already ordered Collections.

**EDIT:**

While working on the problem, I came across a solution how to create a `Spliterator` from an `Iterator`, by converting it into an `Iterable` via `Lambda` first and get the `ORDERED` characteristic from that like so:

```
Iterator iter = new ArrayList().iterator();
boolean isOrdered = ((Iterable)() -> ((Iterator)t1)).spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
```

Unfortunately, this won't preserve the `ORDERED` nature from the original `ArrayItr` and `isOrdered` will be `false`.

I'd have expected it to give the same result (`true`) as

```
boolean isOrdered = new ArrayList().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(ORDERED);
```

but it doesn't. Why is that and how to prevent losing the ordering in the first case - and is creating a spliterator 'expensive'?

**EDIT:**
From what I see in the `Spliterator` doc, the reason should be:

*Impl Note: The default implementation should usually be overridden. The spliterator returned by the default implementation [...] does not report any spliterator characteristics.*

So then the question would boil down to:
"Is it possible to create a Spliterator with preserved characteristics from the first case, whithout a custom overridden implementation?".

Comment: An `Iterator` has no characteristics. This lambda construct is just an obfuscated way to call [`Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliteratorUnknownSize(java.util.Iterator,int)) and the resulting characteristics are the ones passed to that method, which in this case, are none, as none are known. There is no magic that could inject characteristics when the characteristics are not known.

Comment: But anyway, you said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75901821#comment133912922_75901821) that you want to know whether it “*will iterate elements in the order they were added to the Collection*” but the `ORDERED` characteristic only implies that there might be *some meaning* to the iteration order, not that it is the insertion order. Most notably, a `SortedSet`’s iteration order is *not* the insertion order. Even a `List` does not always reflect the insertion order; it only does when you always added at the end. But you still could call `Collections.shuffle(list)` anytime

Comment: You're right, of course, I've only referenced to the most basic/obvious ordering. Because the `Iterator` in the example is created from an `Array`, internally it's based on `ArrayItr`, which is ordered. I figured that the standard `Spliterator` implementations would check for such obvious cases and add the appropriate characteristics. Too bad.